# CloudifySource 2.2 GA and 2.3 M2 not working on Windows 8

Tags: cloud, cloudify

Has anybody got 2.2 GA or 2.3 M2 working on Windows 8 Ent x64? I have installed JDK 1.7.x and set JAVA_HOME and PATH as instructed in the install guide.

All errors indicate that the agent cannot start. It would also seem that this IS NOT because there's another agent running. When I try a shutdown-agent or teardown-localcloud it says it cannot find any agents.

I have switched off the windows firewall. all 3 firewall profiles are off; domain, private, and public.

Verbose output from the bootstrap-localcloud command is below. Any ideas on how to fix, where to look, how to verify the install etc.?

```
cloudify@default> bootstrap-localcloud --verbose
NIC Address=127.0.0.1
Lookup Locators=127.0.0.1:4176
Lookup Groups=localcloud
Bootstrapping localcloud, this may take a few minutes
Starting agent and management processes:
cmd.exe /c @call "gs.bat" start startLH startGSM startESM startGSA gsa.global.lus 0 gsa.lus 0 gsa.gsc 0 gsa.global.gsm 0 gsa.gsm_l
us 0 gsa.global.esm 0 gsa.esm 0 >nul 2>&1
STARTING CLOUDIFY MANAGEMENT
Operation failed. org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.CLIException: Error while starting agent. Please make sure that another agent
is not already running. Command executed: cmd.exe /c @call C:\Program Files\CloudifySource\bin\"gs.bat" start startLH startGSM sta
rtESM startGSA gsa.global.lus 0 gsa.lus 0 gsa.gsc 0 gsa.global.gsm 0 gsa.gsm_lus 0 gsa.global.esm 0 gsa.esm 0 >nul 2>&1
at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.runCommand(LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.java:1302)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.runGsAgentOnLocalHost(LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.
java:751)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.startManagementOnLocalhostAndWaitInternal(LocalhostGr
idAgentBootstrapper.java:801)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.installer.LocalhostGridAgentBootstrapper.startLocalCloudOnLocalhostAndWait(LocalhostGridAgentB
ootstrapper.java:329)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.BootstrapLocalCloud.doExecute(BootstrapLocalCloud.java:110)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.commands.AbstractGSCommand.execute(AbstractGSCommand.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:35)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:474)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:400)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.jline.Console.run(Console.java:221)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:191)
at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.Main.run(Main.java:89)
at org.cloudifysource.shell.GigaShellMain.main(GigaShellMain.java:122)
```

Thread on CloudifySource is here
https://cloudifysource.zendesk.com/entries/22477167-2-2-ga-and-2-3-m2-not-working-on-windows-8

Thanks

Comment: please embed the details in the post body, as questions are expected to be self contained (what happens if the link breaks?), thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the problem you are experiencing. though i could only reproduce this when i point my JAVA_HOME to a JRE distribution outside the JDK.

are you sure you are working with the JDK?

try running %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac, if you cant run this command it means you are running with a JRE or with some strange JDK distribution.

i suggest installing this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downlo... and trying again.

make sure you JAVA_HOME points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10...

let me know if you are still seeing this issue.